# Отправка email с помощью javax.mail в Java

Tags: java, потоки-данных, email, шаблоны-проектирования

В общем ситуация такая: есть таблица в БД, с которой должны выбираться электронные почты для отправки на них писем.

Класс `Message` имеет метод `addRecipients`, который позволяет отправлять письмо многим пользователям (то есть создавать копию при отправке), но некоторые почтовые серверы понимают похожи рассылки, как спам, и другие пользователи будут видеть кому еще отправляются письма да и получателей может быть много.

Поэтому я решил делать несколько по-другому.. как известно, для отправки сообщения нужен объект `Session`. Я сделал класс `SingletonSession`, в котором реализовал паттерн `Singleton`. Итак, мы имеем инициализированный объект `session`. Далее я создаю несколько потоков, в которых создаю много объектов `Message`, в их конструкторы передаю уже готовый объект `Session`. Ну и дальше в соответствии отправляю сообщение.

Меня интересует есть какие-то другие способы решения проблемы рассылки многих сообщений, этот способ экономит время, но я не знаю могут быть какие-то проблемы из-за многопоточности.

Answer (score 1):

```
и другие пользователи будут видеть кому еще отправляются письма да и получателей может быть много
```

Есть такая штука, называется [BCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy).
Java Mail предоставляет API для использования данной штуки:

```
addRecipient(Message.RecipientType type,
                     Address address)
```

([ссылка](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Message.html#addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType,%20javax.mail.Address)))